# CurrentRegion.Select and Table format in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm very new (1 week) to visual basic and basically I'm trying to automate some repetitive work, now to the point , within a number of files produced with varying data I need to format the selected range as a table (medium 9) but i'm in a block at the moment  and need some help and would really appreciate it, here is what i have so far>>>>

```
  Option Explicit

Dim strDate, strRepDate, strPath, strPathRaw , strDate2

dim dteTemp, dteDay, dteMth, dteYear, newDate, myDate

myDate = Date()
dteTemp = DateAdd("D", -1, myDate)
dteDay = DatePart("D", dteTemp)
dteMth = DatePart("M", dteTemp)
dteYear = DatePart("YYYY", dteTemp)

If (Len(dteDay) = 1) Then dteDay = "0" & dteDay
If (Len(dteMth) = 1) Then dteMth = "0" & dteMth

strDate = dteYear&"-"&dteMth&"-"&dteDay
strDate2 = dteYear&""&dteMth&""&dteDay

Dim objXLApp, objXLWb, objXLWs

Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CuRrY\Desktop\"&strDate2&"\Agent Daily Disposition  "&strDate2&".xls")
objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
'start excell
Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)
'objXLWs.Cells(Row, Column ).Value 

  With objXLWs
  objXLWs.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Agent Name"
  'objXLWs.Range("A3").Select
  objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select


 'End With
```

as you can see i reached as far as CurrentRegion.Select but how to format selected cells into (medium 9) i've tried so much and failed 
Thanks for any help

Comment: Ok update - I have been playing around with codes and well instead of using Currentregion.select I simply found the last cell with data then  let Vb return the cell address now that I have the range that varies with different files at different dates example (A2:D85), now  how can I format it as a table medium 9 within VB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the CurrentRegion(which represents a Range object) through the SpecialCells Submethod. Although your conditions are specific to your xls sheet, you will still have to follow the formatting available through the specialcells() method properties. Also, by utilizing the currentregion property, the page assumes you have a xls header. So it is important to verify your table structure before trying to incorporate this property.

For instance:

```
Sub FillIn()
  Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 _
  = "=R[-1]C"
  Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
End Sub
```

View the available properties that can be applied to CurrentRegion -> [Here](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174338&seqNum=12)
And the MSDN Article -> [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thx man I'm basically automating the rest of my work i have to do this stuff 2AM in the morning and sometimes fall asleep cause its so boring I'm going to look into this tonight and will let you know and again thx i owe you one :)